# force presto execute sql fragment (a view with where conditions ) in target database

Tags: presto

In Presto, I'm writting a SQL to fetch data from a view with 6 tables. Those tables are all pretty huge whose records is from 5 Millions to 30 Millions.
The SQL as below:

```
select
  a, b, c, d
from db.schema.v_order
where
  f_order_code in (
    select order_code from anotherdb.schema.xxx where ......
  )
```

I have tried to fetch result from the subquery, and replace the subquery with the content, then execute this sql directly in mysql. It's fast with indexes.
But when I execute this SQL in Presto, I found that Presto always fetch whole view records without any where conditions. This is very slow.

Can I get the result of subquery as the view's where condition and force execute this sql fragment in mysql? Or is there any other solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long standing in Presto. This is tracked by the following Github issue: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/18. Also, https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/684 is related.

As a workaround, you can define a VIEW directly in your database (here: mysql).

If semi-join (`IN`) is across separate catalogs, the only workaround currently is to pull data from one table and pass it to query as constants.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
Is this related to the plan of aggregation pushdown in mysql (#4138)? It's not compelet yet. 
But I noticed that PostgreSQL has been supported, is that mean I can resolve this problem by changing my database server from MySQL to PostgreSQL?

Comment: @bahborben your query is not an aggregation query, so switching to PostgreSQL shouldn't change anything at the moment.